# Conditionally suppress infowindows suppressInfoWindows Google Maps

Tags: google-maps-api-3, infowindow

Wanting to suppress infoWindow if mobile so that content can be shown in sidebar as per example.

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  map: map,
  animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
  position: point,

  suppressInfoWindows: true,

  icon: icon
});
```

I don't know Javascript well enough to be able to do it.

I have Js to detect mobile. if( isMobile.any() ) alert('Mobile');

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: If you think the question is resolved, mark the answer that helped you as accepted or create a new one instead of editing your question.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of suppress an `InfoWindow`, just create one only when your're not on mobile.

```
if (!isMobile.any()){
    //createInfoWindow
}
```